# Why doesn't form validation work?

Tags: html

I don't understand. How come form validation doesn't work?

**CODE EDIT**

```
    <form action="https://s1368768478.t.eloqua.com/e/f2" id="form103" method="post" name="prenumerera">
    <input name="elqFormName" type="hidden" value="prenumerera">
    <input name="elqSiteId" type="hidden" value="1368768478">
    <input name="elqCampaignId"type="hidden">
    <label for="field0"></label>
    <input id="email" name="email" placeholder="E-postadress" required="" type="email" value="">
    <input id="field1" name="site" type="hidden" value="1">
    <button value="Submit">Prenumerera</button>
    </form>
```

http://www.sitepoint.com/html5-form-validation/

**EDIT**

I need the input to be an emailadress, and give an error message if not so.

Comment: What do you mean by this?

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work?

Comment: your question is not clear .what you want do  ?

Comment: which browser you using ?

Comment: Sorry edited now, I want the input only to be emailadresses, and i'm using chrome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

are you sure you have a valid form?

you need a submit button and a valid form for this ..

```
<form name="loginForm">
<input type="email" name="email" id="email" required/>
<input type="submit" value="save" />
</form>
```

Try this...

Comment: Please do not use <button> use input type="submit" it will work

Comment: Why cant use button? And only input type="submit" ?

Comment: check this out - https://jsfiddle.net/c0y5ocrh/ works for me..

Comment: A valid form needs a submit button to work, it submits the form-handler http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp